# Minimum required properties in ESAPI.properties

Tags: java, esapi

My web application uses only the following ESAPI encode methods:

- `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForLDAP()`
- `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML()`

In this case, what is the minimum required properties in ESAPI.properties?

Now I'm using ESAPI 2.1.0.1 and [this properties](https://github.com/k-tamura/easybuggy/blob/master/src/main/resources/ESAPI.properties).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just using the encoder() function, the 3 lines in the encoder section is all you need. Lines 99-119 (between all the comments).

**Edit** 
Plus you must specify a default encoder. Example:

```
ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder

Encoder.AllowMultipleEncoding=false

Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding=false

Encoder.DefaultCodecList=HTMLEntityCodec,PercentCodec,JavaScriptCodec
```

Comment: It seems to work fine (vote+1) but I always get the noisy message `SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.Encoder not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder`. So I added `ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder`.

Comment: Ok, i will edit the answer to include that. Thank you for adding this.

Answer (score 3):

I think I answered a previous question.

Again you're the victim of some bad design choices back at the beginning of the ESAPI project between 2009-2011. Namely, the Singleton-based monolith.

ESAPI's current design is monolithic, meaning it tries to be everything to everyone.  As you're well aware, this isn't the best design strategy, but that's where we're at.

We have several proposals for breaking various functions out into separate libraries, but that's future work towards building ESAPI 3.0.

For your current dilemma, there's too much of the library that is dependent upon functionality that it sounds like you don't need and don't intend to use.  Unfortunately, that is simply the current fact of life.  No one has ever seemed to use our authentication interface--but its there for everybody, even if they don't need it.  Most users use our encoding/decoding capability first, followed by the validation API and then crypto.  The last couple are log injection and the WAF.

Most users of ESAPI take the non-prod test file, and leave it at that.  (This is a *really* bad idea.)

The others take the one you reference and work through the exceptions, asking us questions on the mailing list.

This is not an ideal path to walk either, but it's the path we're in right now.

The danger from my perspective, is if you choose to implement happy-path configurations for the ones ESAPI is throwing exceptions towards, with the goal of JUST making it happy so you can get to your two narrow use-cases.

Then you get promoted and another developer on your app is faced with a problem that she thinks is solved because you handled all the integration with ESAPI.

PAY ATTENTION TO THE PARTS OF ESAPI THAT DON'T PERTAIN TO YOUR USE CASE.  This isn't ideal, but its where we're at in 2017. Ask us questions on the user list.

Failure to do so--especially in the crypto portion, will leave your application vulnerable in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your information (vote+1). I understand the background but I want to know the minimum required properties.
I think it is the following: `ESAPI.printProperties=true`, `LogLevel=ERROR`, `ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder`, `Encoder.AllowMultipleEncoding=false`, `Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding=false`, `Encoder.DefaultCodecList=HTMLEntityCodec,PercentCodec,JavaScriptCodec`. Is it incorrect?

Comment: We've *never* tested ESAPI with THAT minimal of a set.  I cannot recommend this.  You could clone the ESAPI project and test with a massively truncated file as you suggest, and make a determination on your own if the unit tests that fail are ones you need to care about.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will test carefully.

Answer (score 2):

## RegEx used in ESAPI.validator().getValidInput(..) calls

Validator.COMPANY_ID_PTRN=[a-zA-Z0-9]+
Validator.USER_DN_PTRN=[a-zA-Z0-9=,]+
Validator.ROLE_DN_PTRN=[a-zA-Z0-9=,^\- ]+

## Minimum default settings

ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.encoder.esapi.ESAPIEncoder
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory
Logger.ApplicationName=TrianzApp
Logger.LogEncodingRequired=false
Logger.LogApplicationName=false
Logger.LogServerIP=false
Logger.UserInfo=false
Logger.ClientInfo=false
IntrusionDetector.Disable=true
ESAPI.Validator=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator
Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding=false
Encoder.AllowMultipleEncoding=false
ESAPI.printProperties=false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).